# How to perform exploratory factor analysis on associative network?

Tags: r, factor-analysis, networks

In an [article](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/umz3wx28gcjvgh1/RQrbGByACn) by Teichert and Schontag ("Exploring Consumer Knowledge Structure Using Associative Network Analysis", 2010), the authors perform (page 387) 
an exploratory factor analysis (EFA) on an associative network, but they do not provide any practical detail in order to produce a similar analysis.

Does anyone know how to perform EFA of a network? I guess the input should be the adjacency matrix (which is here called "associative matrix" because the network is a network of associations between words/concepts).

It would be great if you could point me to some documentation, maybe in R (that would be perfect!).

Thank you very much.